# How do I download directory with all files and folders inside using npm module ssh2 for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, sftp, ssh2

I am trying to download files and folders via SFTP to my local machine.I am using the below code and am able to download the files in a particular directory but am unable to download the folders(with their respective files and folders recursively) in the same directory

```
 const folderDir=moment().format('MMM YYYY/D');
 const remoteDir = '/var/www/html/view';
 const remoteDir = 'Backup';

const download=(remoteDir,folderDir,FolderName)=>{

conn.on('ready', function() {

    conn.sftp((err, sftp) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      sftp.readdir(remoteDir, (err, list) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let count = list.length;
        list.forEach(item => {
          let remoteFile = remoteDir + '/' + item.filename;
          var localFile = 'C:/Users/Desktop/'+folderDir+'/'+FolderName+'/' + item.filename;
          //console.log('Downloading ' + remoteFile);
          sftp.fastGet(remoteFile, localFile, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            //console.log('Downloaded to ' + localFile);
            count--;
            if (count <= 0) {
              conn.end();
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });



  }).connect({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 0,
    username: 'test',
    privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('')
  });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Install the module by running:

```
npm i ssh2-sftp-client
```

You can do it like this:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();


sftp.connect({
    host: '',
    port: '22',
    username: 'your-username',
    password: 'your-password'
}).then(() => {
    // will return an array of objects with information about all files in the remote folder
    return sftp.list('/');
}).then(async (data) => {
    // data is the array of objects
    len = data.length;
    // x is one element of the array
    await data.forEach(x => {
        let remoteFilePath = '/' + x.name;
        sftp.get(remoteFilePath).then((stream) => {
            // save to local folder ftp
            let file = './ftp/' + x.name;
            fs.writeFile(file, stream, (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
        });
    });

}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'catch error');
});
```

[For more info on the ssh2-sftp-client module.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client)

Comment: Tried this. 2020-07-30T04:46:24.619Z eb774405-eb3d-4d44-9542-c62805734ad7 ERROR (node:8) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit