# Download file using ssh with simple-ssh npm

Tags: node.js, ssh, server, download, remote-access

I need to download a file on the server using ssh from remote to local.
I'm using the simple-ssh module from npm [link to npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh)

I can update a file that is already on the server, however I need to download such a file

```js
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
let ssh = new SSH({
                host: 'remote_server_ip',
                user: 'my_user',
                pass: 'my_pass'
            });
            
            ssh.exec(`cat > ${filePath}`, {
                in: fs.readFileSync('/home/raphael/Documentos/teste.bin')
            }).start();
            
            //my filePath /arq_soa/arquivos_validador/Envio/tst_acesso
```

Can someone help me?, i'm lost

After help of @Carlos Jafet Neto, my code has changed, now:

```js
var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client
            sftp.connect({
                host: 'remote_server_iṕ',
                port: 22,
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }).then(() => {
                return sftp.list(`${pathArquivoValidador}`);
            }).then(async (data) => {
                let len = data.length;
                await data.forEach(x => {
                    let remoteFilePath = `${pathArquivoValidador}` + params.nmArquivo;                    
                    sftp.get(remoteFilePath).then((stream) => {
                        let file = './home/raphael/Documentos/' + params.nmArquivo;
                        fs.writeFile(file, stream, (err) => {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                        });
                    });
                    // console.log(x);
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err, 'catch error');
            });
```

but the `sftp.get` are bringing me the following error

`{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './home/raphael/Documentos/tst_acesso']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './home/raphael/Documentos/tst_acesso' }`

Comment: Hi Raphael! If you do not mind changing. I have an example here in stackoverflow in ssh2-sftp-client in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297097/how-do-i-download-directory-with-all-files-and-folders-inside-using-npm-module-s/55314037#55314037

Comment: man, I'm trying to do the way you teach in your answer, I even get to the files that interest me, but I'm not able to download the file because I get the following error:
`{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './home/raphael/Documentos/tst_acesso']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './home/raphael/Documentos/tst_acesso' }`

Comment: Ok! Can you post your code?

Comment: i just did it thx

Comment: Ok! I wiil take a look and get back to you!

Comment: the '.' in front of the path is probably wrong

Comment: @JeffRSon man, now it's working, you're correct. but now i have one last question, let's assume I want to download this file directly from the client browser, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get first only the files that are in your folders without using variables, using your path as a string to eliminate errors.

```
var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client
            sftp.connect({
                host: 'remote_server_iṕ',
                port: 22,
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }).then(() => {
                return sftp.list('/');
            }).then(async (files) => {
                console.log(files);
                len = files.length;
                await files.forEach(x => {
                    let remoteFilePath = '/' + x.name;
                    sftp.get(remoteFilePath).then((stream) => {
                        let file = './ftp/' + x.name;
                        fs.writeFile(file, stream, (err) => {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err, 'catch error');
            });
```

To get a single file:

```
var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client
            sftp.connect({
                host: 'remote_server_iṕ',
                port: 22,
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }).then(() => {
                let remoteFilePath = '/' + fileName;
                sftp.get(remoteFilePath).then((stream) => {
                    let file = './ftp/' + x.name;
                    fs.writeFile(file, stream, (err) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                    });
                    sftp.end();
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err, 'catch error');
            });
```

Use this to close the ftp connection:

```
sftp.end();
```

Comment: i received this `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Now I have received a array of objects and are the ones I need to download

Comment: Great! Thats it! Now you can do a files.forEach(x =>....the x here will be each element of the array and you can get each file name like this: let remoteFilePath = '/' + x.name; I will update the code there!

Comment: Dear one last doubt, in case I want only one item of all items, I will need a parameter to replace x.name, correct?

Comment: Yes. If you now already the file you do not even need the loop. I will update with this extra solution.

Comment: man, now it's working, i'm done with your help and the JeffRSon. but now i have one last question, let's assume I want to download this file directly from the client browser, how would I do that?

Comment: You would need to make a get request to the browser with the full path of your file! You can do this with the request module. Take a look: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: One last thing we need to do! Close our ftp connection! I will update the code there!